# mod_rewrite file check with extention

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

Here is my .htaccess for simple url rewriting for any MVC architecture.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /personal/site/

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Every thing is working only **one exception** rises. On the root where `index.php` exists i created a file `generator.js`, i also do have a controller named generator.

So for a request, `http://localhost/personal/site/generator/css`,

it must rewrite it to  `http://localhost/personal/site/index.php/generator/css`

But it is rewriting it to `http://localhost/personal/site/generator.js/css`

How to resolve this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off multiviews.

```
Options -MultiViews
```